# MS-SQL Express 2005/2008 multi instance CPU and memory utilization

Tags: sql-server, memory, cpu

With SQL Express (either 2005 or 2008 edition) there is a limit of 1GB memory and 1 CPU that can be used. What I'm wondering, is if two instances are installed on the same machine, would they use the same CPU and same 1GB of memory? Or, would they use potentially two different CPU's and 2GB memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limitations are per-instance. Each instance is limited to its own 1 CPU and 1GB RAM.

You can have up to 16 instances of SQL Server Express Edition on a system.

Also in MSDE, the predecessor to SQL Server Express, the limitations were per-instance.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know this 100% for sure?

Comment: I'm pretty sure of it. This was the case for MSDE and I believe the limitations are per-instance. In fact, it's only logical. How would an instance know about the other's memory usage at any time!? Assume they are running on two different accounts without permission to access each other.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for sure, but most likely they would be able to use separate CPUs and memory. It would be pretty tricky for them to coordinate to share memory like that. My suspicion is that each instance will run the same irrespective of other instances being present (at least in the respect you're talking about).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your system has 4 CPU and suppose 4 GB memory, and 2 instances of sql express, then each express will make utilization of one CPU and 1 GB Memory .
Hope it helps